# How to change CircularFillableLoaders color?

Tags: android, process

I am using [CircularFillableLoader](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/2897) and I want to change loader bar color like code

```
<com.mikhaellopez.circularfillableloaders.CircularFillableLoaders
            android:id="@+id/circularFillableLoaders"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/your_logo"
            app:cfl_border="true"
            app:cfl_border_width="12dp"
            app:cfl_progress="80"
            app:cfl_wave_amplitude="0.06"
            app:cfl_wave_color="#3f51b5" />
```

JAVA

```
 CircularFillableLoaders circularFillableLoaders = (CircularFillableLoaders)findViewById(R.id.yourCircularFillableLoaders);
    // Set Wave and Border Color
 circularFillableLoaders.setColor(Color.RED);//Error when add this line
```

and i try with another code , it still not work.

```
int color = Color.parseColor("#1F45FC")
```

i got error message when device loading ? What is wrong with this code
Could you help me?, please
Thank you.

Comment: Can you also add the error stacktrace (from logcat) to your question.

Answer (score 0):

as i got from you it is simple just change  app:cfl_wave_color="#3f51b5" 
and change #3f51b5 to color code without java code

Comment: Thank you for help ,I want to change in activity is not layout.